# Styling django widget in wizard form

Tags: django, django-forms

I am facing an issue with widgets in forms. I have 3 steps ( 3 forms ) in a django wizard and I want to style each field.

If I loop the forms to style each field separately it seems to work but, it doesn't work with the fields I have as widgets in my model ( they appear styled but the input is not recognized ).

For example, I have 2 radiobuttons in one form, and if I use type="checkbox" to style the field in the template, it doesn't work. The same with textarea fields, I can render a textarea but the form doesn't recognize the input.
Is there a way to style the widgets ?

```
{% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
{% for field in form %}
<label class="control-label" for="id_{{ field.name }}">Message</label>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="10" cols="10"
id="id_{{ field.name }}" value="{{ field.value }}"
onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value='{{field.name}}'}" 
onfocus="if (this.value == '{{field.name}}') {this.value=''}" > </textarea>
<p class="help-text">{{ field.help_text }} </p> 
{% endfor %} 
{% endfor %}
```

That renders the widget field (widget=forms.Textarea) as a text area, but as de field is defined as a widget is the value isn't recognized by the form.

Answer (score 0):

Adding widgets in **forms.py** is the best way to do so. Like so:

```
from django import forms
class CabModelForm( forms.ModelForm ):
    descr = forms.CharField( widget=forms.Textarea )
    class Meta:
        model = Cab
```

Start with this for your form:

```
<form action="/contact/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Does your form worK? It should at least work with this minimal code. If not, you have an error somewhere in your views.py most likely.

Comment: I have that widget, but I cann't apply any style to it in a template. I have updated with the code. If I use the code I've added, I get a text area but not the input.

Comment: I'd say it has something to do with your javascript "onblur" and "onfocus".  the simplest way to test is just to put your form in the template as {{ form.as_p }} and see if it works from there.

Comment: printing directly the form with {{form}} or {{form.as_p}} works, but doing that I cannot put any style on the field.

Comment: you can wrap the form in a <div> and style it that way. other than that not sure. with javascript. good luck.